# How to obtain nodal coordinates with respect to local coordinate system in ABAQUS

Tags: python, abaqus

I want to use nodal coordinates wrt local coordinate system in my code. I am not sure how to obtain it. I will be requiring these coordinates in modifying my odb file as well. I am not sure if using *TRANSFORM or writing all my results wrt local coordinate system will work as there are multiple parts in my model and I require information wrt Global coordinate system.

I think even of I am able to get information about the relative orientation of the local CS wrt global(Euler angles), that would also work.

Comment: This sort of question is completely off-topic for [SO]

Comment: what code are you talking about?